Does this convergent Taylor series converge to the right answer everywhere within its radius of convergence?
Suppose I have a function $f(x)$ whose Taylor series in $x$ about $x=0$ converges to $f(x)$ for all $x$, and $f(0) \neq 0$.
I write down the formal Taylor series for $\log(f(x))$ about $x=0$, and I see that the formal series has a finite radius of convergence $R>0$. Let us define $g(x)$ by noting that within the radius of convergence, the series for $\log(f(x))$ converges to $g(x)$.
Does $\log(f(x)) = g(x)$ for $|x| < R$?
Does $f(x)$ not equal zero for $|x| < R$?

My analysis is a bit weak, and the above is a toy problem I've invented as practice (inspired by statistical mechanics).
Here is my thinking.
Since $f(0)$ is not equal to zero, and $f(x)$ is analytic everywhere and in particular at $0$, I believe that means $f(x)$ is not equal to zero within some open set $O$ containing zero. As pointed out by J.Dmaths, this follows immediately from the fact that analytic functions are continuous.
Then because a composition of analytic functions is analytic, and $\log(x)$ is analytic away from $x=0$, $\log(f(x))$ is analytic in the open set $O$ around $x=0$. Since series representations are unique, this means that $\log(f(x))$ is equal to $g(x)$ in that open set $O$.
However, I'm not sure whether or not this means that $\log(f(x))$ is equal to $g(x)$ everywhere in the interval $|x| < R$ where the series for $\log(f(x))$ converges. I think the fact that $f(x)$ is analytic everywhere is very important (importantly, if $f(x)$ were just analytic within some region $|x| < R' < R$, then it needn't be true that $\log(f(x)) = g(x)$ for $R' < |x| < R$), but I'm not sure how I would use it. I likely am missing an important theorem.

Just a comment as it sounds like you were hesitant about this fact: To formalise "Since f(0) is not equal to zero, and f(x)  is analytic everywhere and in particular at 0 , I believe that means f(x) is not equal to zero within some open set O containing zero", by the fact that f(x) is a continuous function(as it is analytic), there must be some delta-neighborhood around zero s.t f(x)>0 or f(x)<0 if f(0) $\neq$ 0
